# Django - ImportError: No module named 'myproject.settings'; 'myproject' is not a package

Tags: django, python-3.x, jenkins

I startet a Django project with the name `emus`. Here is the (short) structure:

```
emus/  ### <-- renamed "emus" to "grp"
    __init__.py
    urls.py
    settings/...
    core/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        migrations/
            __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views/...
        static/...
        template/...
manage.py
requirements
tests
```

After a while of working we decided to rename emus to grp. This was done by a teammate with PyCharm an the builtin function to change all depencies. He had to edit some files anyway.
The project worked on his local machine. When i pulled it I got instantly the Error: `ImportError: No module named 'grp.settings'; 'grp' is not a package` (whole error log below)
After setting up a new VM the new build worked for me as well but not for jenkins. There we have still the same error.

Here is the full Error log:

`$ python manage.py <any>`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/chkoenig/.virtualenvs/grp_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/chkoenig/.virtualenvs/grp_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/chkoenig/.virtualenvs/grp_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/chkoenig/.virtualenvs/grp_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/chkoenig/.virtualenvs/grp_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/chkoenig/.virtualenvs/grp_dev/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2221, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'grp.settings'; 'grp' is not a package
```

How is something like that possible?
A code isn't working but after setting up a new VM (with exactly the same settings - I use a script for alle the packages and settings) it works without any error.

Any ideas how to solve this error in jenkins?
Thanks in advance

btw.: Python 3.4.3 with virtualenv and Django 1.8.5
Another (maybe unnecessary) info: the foldername of our project is also called `grp`. Changing this didn't solve it.

-- update: my manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "grp.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Can you post your manage.py?

Comment: Thanks. Is your project path into the python sys.path?

Comment: nope my python is in `usr/local/bin/python3.4` and my project is in `home/user/Desktop`. If that is what you asked for.

Comment: just in case someone come up with the same problem. The solution was to rename the whole project from `grp` to s.th. else because grp is a builtin module in unix.

Answer (score 0):

Search for references to 'emus' still in the source code

```
cd emus
grep -rni 'emus' ./
```

Change any 'emus' to 'grp'

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I already found the solution (I commented the OP). The solution was to rename the whole project from grp to s.th. else because grp is a builtin module in unix.